# Basic usage of swffit. How to make it work

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash

How swffit (http://swffit.millermedeiros.com/) can be used? I mean in my project I have dynamically expanding flash application, so once the expanding part riches the bottom I see standard flash scroll bar. Not browser scrollbar...

Here is how I defined my application:

```
        public function addPanel(evt:Event):void
        {
            var panel:Panel = new Panel();
                panel.name = "new";
                panel.title = "new";
                panel.height = 30;
                panel.width = 100;
            this.addChild(panel);
            SWFFit.fit('my_flash', 800, 600);
        }


        public function main(event:Event):void{
            SWFFit.fit('my_flash', 800, 600);


        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Button label="Add" click="addPanel(event)"/>
```

The html file (same as described in docs):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swffit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      swfobject.registerObject("my_flash", "8.0.0");
      swffit.fit("my_flash",800,600);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <object id="my_flash" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="movie" value="Sample.swf" />
      <!--[if !IE]>-->
      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Sample.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <div>
      <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" title="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a><br />
      You need <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Flash Player 8</a> and allow javascript to see the content of this site..
    </div>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
      </object>
      <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>

  </body>
</html>
```

Will be happy to hear any feedback,

---

Added fixes described in answer 1. but come across interesting issue: e.g. browser scroll bar appears only on browser window resize, not when clicking add button...

http://img.skitch.com/20100210-qx9trerh8rq5athhnuwtidetr6.png

After add is clicked several times, I see flash default scroll bar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [SWFFit Tutorial](http://www.hectorarandawebworx.com/main/swffit-tutorial-fullscreen-flash-site-with-browser-scrollbars).

And test to see if changing your `width="300" height="300"` to `width="100%" height="100%"` does anything.  If you have that and the explicit sizes in `swffit.fit("my_flash", 800, 600);`, swffit sets the minimum size, so if your browser viewport is below them, the scrollbars appear, if it's above them, the swf resizes too 100% width and height.

Then to dynamically resize your swf from Actionscript, use the `com.millermedeiros.swffit.SWFFit` class.  You can call `SWFFit.fit(...)` and a few other methods from ActionScript and it will do all the javascript to resize it.

There's a few sample .fla's in the [swffit source](http://swffit.googlecode.com/files/swffit_2_4_beta.zip), take a look at how they do it there.

Update: Here is some code that demonstrates how to resize the swf from within ActionScript.

**Sample App**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="absolute">

    <mx:Script>
        import com.millermedeiros.swffit.*;

        public static const FLASH_ID:String = "my_flash";

        public function updateSize():void
        {
            var width:Number = widthSlider.value;
            var height:Number = heightSlider.value;
            trace("width: ", width, " height: ", height);
            SWFFit.fit(FLASH_ID, width, height);
        }
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Panel backgroundColor="0xaaaaaa" width="80%" height="80%"
        horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>

    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Label text="Width"/>
        <mx:HSlider id="widthSlider" liveDragging="true" change="updateSize()"
            minimum="300" maximum="2000"/>
        <mx:Label text="Height"/>
        <mx:HSlider id="heightSlider" liveDragging="true" change="updateSize()"
            minimum="300" maximum="2000"/>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

**Sample HTML Template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swffit.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            swfobject.registerObject("my_flash", "10.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
            swffit.fit("my_flash", 800, 600);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <object id="my_flash" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%">
            <param name="movie" value="Sample.swf" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Sample.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
        <!--<![endif]-->

        <div>
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" title="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a><br />
            You need <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Flash Player 10</a> and allow javascript to see the content of this site..
        </div>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>

    </body>
</html>
```

Best,
Lance

Comment: I am using flex builder (and flex), and a little but confused about how to look at those flas code?

So will be more then happy to get short example in actionscript...